# Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT. Реальный путь до файла ЛЮБОГО расширения

Tags: java, android, android-intent

Реализован выбор файлов пользователем. Выбирать он может файлы **любого** расширения. Необходимо узнать **реальный путь до файла** (не uri), так как потом этот файл отправляется на удалённый сервер и для этого нужен именно реальный путь.
Есть такой код:

```
public  String getFilePath(Uri uri) {
    String selection = null;
    String[] selectionArgs = null;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19 && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(this, uri)) {
        if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
            final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final String[] split = docId.split(":");
            return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];
        } else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {
            final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId( Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id));
        } else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
            final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final String[] split = docId.split(":");
            final String type = split[0];
            if ("image".equals(type)) {
                uri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
                uri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
                uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            }
            selection = "_id=?";
            selectionArgs = new String[]{split[1]};
        }
    }
    if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
        String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        Cursor cursor = null;
        try {
            cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null);
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                return cursor.getString(column_index);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        } finally { if (cursor != null)   cursor.close();
        }
    } else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
        return uri.getPath();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Работает прекрасно, но только для медиафайлов (картинки, видео, аудио). Мне же нужно, чтобы работал для всех расширений (особенно pdf, zip). Ошибка при попытке выбрать файл другого типа:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=777, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/raw:/storage/emulated/0/Download/oferta.pdf flg=0x43 }} to activity {com.example.myapp/com.example.mytestapp.MyActivity}: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "raw:/storage/emulated/0/Download/oferta.pdf"
```

Причём в тексте ошибки по сути присутствует сам нужный мне путь. Более того, при выборе pdf-файла из другой дирректории (не Download) ошибка почему-то не вылетает и путь определяется верно. Подскажите, что подправить в коде, чтобы вытащить **реальный путь к файлу любого типа из uri** без ошибок?

Comment: никаких реальных путей у пользователя вы не получите, и на практике это не нужно, доступ к файлу через stream

Comment: Можно подробнее об этом? Вообще дело в том, что для отправки файла серверу с помощью библиотеки okhttp необходим именно реальный путь к файлу

Comment: Подробнее? - Андроид давно и настойчиво уходит от прямого доступа к файлам в пользу SAF и DocumentProvider. К всеобщему сожалению это и не удобно, и глупо, и не поддерживается сторонними, тем более pure-java, библиотеками, но господам не объяснишь, что они идиоты. Единственный 100% выход в вашем случае - открыть поток через `context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(Uri)` и передать этот поток библиотеке, если такой вариант поддерживается, иначе сохранить его во временный файл и отдать библиотеке путь этого файла.

Answer (score 1):

Ну у вас есть URI, вызовите

```
new File(uri.getPath());
```

И вот вам файл который вы можете отправить куда угодно.

Ну или просто `uri.getPath();`

Comment: То, что выводится в результате, совсем не похоже на реальный путь

Comment: Так причем тут похоже или нет. У вас есть uri - это и есть ссылка на файл. Вы можете из URI получить как сам файл так и путь.

Comment: Если передать путь, полученный с помощью uri.getPath(), картинка не отправляется на сервер. Если же отправлять по реальному пути, который и выглядит как реальный, то отправляется. Библиотека okhttp

Comment: E/MyLogTag: Other Error: /document/image:284991: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Answer (score 0):

Возможно вам поможет метод `getRealPathFromURI(data.getData())`.

`data` - полученный файл

```
private String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {

        String[] proj = { MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
}
```

---

**Еще методы:**

**1.** `context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri)`

**2.** `context.getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(uri, "r")?.getFileDescriptor()`